# Background jobs in Microsoft Bot Framework in Teams Channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a teams bot and I need to run a timer outside of the turnContext. What is the correct way to do it?
Right now, I am doing it inside a dialog but when the dialog ends, the timer is cancelled. I need to trigger the timer inside a dialog but it need to run long after the dialog ends.

I have the bot in C# and SDK v4

Comment: Hi @dbucceh Do you want to send messages inside a timer and where exactly you want to use timer. Could you please explain your scenario with more details.

Comment: Yes, I need to send a message inside the timer. What I need to do is start the timer at some point during the conversation with the bot. However, the conversation needs to continue as the timer is active and when it ends, I need to send another message to the user. That is why I need to run it as a background job, but I don't know exactly where I need to start the timer in order to do this.

Comment: Have you tried create a timer object in startup.cs file

Comment: Please let us know if you still persists the issue.

Comment: I am actually trying to manage the timers using a function app with queue messages! so I am hoping that will work

Comment: @dbucceh Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L34).

Comment: Yes! thank you! I will definitely try this after the timer ends to send the proactive message!

Answer (score 0):

You can send message using Timer to  teams, When you receive the event from the bot you can start the Timer and send message when Timer Ends using the [proactive message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L34).
You can use Loops to set the time and send messages.